# fit div height according to parent div, then vertical-align div content

Tags: html, css, height, vertical-alignment

i have 2 div children floated (left and right) in 1 row.
First div's height is higher then second div. So what i want to do is:

1. Fit second div height according to the parent container, so it will
   be the same for both children
2. Vertical-align the content of the second div

I tried

```
.container { overflow: hidden; }
#boxLeft{ width: 50%; float: left;}
#boxRight{ width: 50%; float: right; line-height: 100% }
#box2Right p{ text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;}
```

but line-height: 100% is not working (is working with pixels but i MUST use 100% because i have different rows with different heights).

I also would like to avoid using table if it's possible.

this is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qYBfu/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `display:table`  like this:

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/qYBfu/4/

```
.container { 
    display:table;
}
#boxLeft{ 
    display:table-cell;
}
#boxRight{ 
    display:table-cell;
}
```

You can check this question: [Are floats bad? What should be used in its place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place)

Hope this helps:

Answer (score 1):

For make both divs containers same "height", you can use the following code:

```
 #boxRight{ width: 50%; float: right;  background: silver; line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: -99999px; padding-bottom: 99999px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qYBfu/5/

And what is not clear for me is if you want to align the right content in the middle of the column.

In that case, I think either you have to align only one row, where you can use height & line height equal to the left column (that imply to know the height in advance) or use a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can stretch the left div to full height of parent by making the parent positioned and applying `position:absolute;` `top:0; bottom:0` to the left div.

for aligning the text vertically, you can make use of css3 flex box (*if ancient browser support is not an issue, hopefully*)

```
.container {
 position:relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#boxLeft {
 width: 50%;
 display:inline-block;
 background: silver;
}
#boxRight {
 display:-webkit-flex;
 -webkit-align-items:center;
 -webkit-justify-content:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 width: 50%;
 background: pink;
 text-align:center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYBfu/7/)

Answer (score 0):

This technique just uses css :before pseudo-element, without absolute positioning

```
.container { white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; }
```

You can avoid the text-align, just add it if you want your boxes centered

```
.container:before{ content:""; width: 1px; height: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }

.item{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; white-space: normal; text-align: center; width: 30%; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qYBfu/9/