# How to center multiple divs with float left?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need a gallery of images. Thereby it should be responsive. When there are too many images for one line, they should be displayed in the next.
That's what I have already implemented. My problem now is that the last line (when it has just one image for example) is centered, too. But It should be floated left.

I tried `float:left`, but this just makes everything float left and not center anymore.

Here is an [JSFiddle-Example](https://jsfiddle.net/uLo6r47g/2/).

How can I have the last image float left?

HTML:

```
<div class="psAppWrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="app in applications track by $index" class="psAppTile">
        <img src="{{app.icon}}" class="psAppIcon"/>
        <p class="psAppTitle">{{app.title}}</p>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.psAppIcon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.psAppTitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.psAppTile {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.psAppWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**EDIT**

When I add float left it looks like this:
[image]

The red one is `psAppWrapper`. Here you can see that the images are not centered. The left ones have much less space to the left than the right ones to the right. The spaces should be the same.

Comment: Your question is a bit confuse. Also where you say they should be shown like this there is no example. Please fix and will try to help.

Comment: Sry for this! I hope you can understand it better now.

Comment: use media queries and do what @anurag said for width's < 768px or whatever you need

Comment: Do they *have* to be centered using `float left`, or are other techniques allowed as well?

Comment: They are allowed :)

Comment: Essentially, there is NO **native** layout method that can do this...that's not the way the line box model works. Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items

Answer (score 2):

This

```
.psAppWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left; /* Changed this from text-align:center */
}
```

should align the last element to the left.

Comment: This aligns everything to left. The "complete" lines should stay like they are.

Comment: Use a parent around e.g. <div class='psAppWrapperParent'><div class='psAppWrapper'>...</div></div>,  use text-align: center to align the children of .psAppWrapperParent, and then use text-align: left as shown above for the .psAppWrapper

Comment: Also, width: 100% for the . psAppWrapper will make it take the whole width of the parent. As I understand, you need to keep .psAppWrapper in the center of the parent, and children of .psAppWrapper left-aligned, you need to use display:inline-block for .psAppWrapper, and reduce the width of .psAppWrapper according to your requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. I added the div `psAppWrapperParent` around the `psAppWrapper` and gave it the style `text-align: center`. When I try it like this (and the code in you answer), everything is still floating left.

Comment: Have updated your fiddle, let me know if this helps https://jsfiddle.net/uLo6r47g/5/

Comment: Adding `width: 100%` and so on did not work either. Maybe I can not express what I mean. I will edit my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130408/discussion-between-anurag-and-chocolate-cake).

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, positioning block items via `float: left;` is considered bad practise. You should use `display: flex;` to align block items in the way you like. For the last row, use `flex-wrap: wrap;`. So you should end up with this CSS:

```
.psAppTile {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[You can find explanations and more information on display:flex; here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

But I think that you'll need another technique, `display: grid;` might do the trick. I must admit that I've not yet used this for layout. [You can find a complete guide here.][3]

Comment: Everything is left when I add this. I can't just add it to the last row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place

Comment: The article you provided is more than 12 years old... "That is precisely the case.  float was never meant as a layout tool.  I summarized the history of floats in the article “Containing Floats“, but the short version is that floats are not supposed to be a design tool.  They’re simply meant to take an element, put it to one side, and let other content flow around it.  That’s all."