# Position of 2nd column in row in HTML table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

The position of the 2nd column in a row in HTML table is not at the right side.

I have a table, in which the first row has a single column with `colspan="2"` and width of the row is set at **100%**, and other two rows have two column and width of the row is set at **90%** (White space between two column should be 10%).

**Demonstration:**

**`EXPECTED`:**

[image: expected]

**`REALITY`:**

[image: reality]

I tried to match my expectations:

```
<td style="positon: relative; right: 0; left: 5%;">
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jainvidhya.co.in/developer/) (Just because `snippet` is not giving an actual result)

Full Code:

```css
.hidden_timer {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible !important
}

.question1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.question1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.question1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid blue;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.table_cstm {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15;
  /* Apply cell spacing */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://docstore.co.in/kbc/style/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="test" class="table table-responsive table_cstm">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="question1" style="justify-content: center; width: 100%;">Who was First President of India?(15204)</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <div id="A1" class="question1" onclick="onSelect(event)">A) M K Gandhi
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="positon: relative; right: 0; left: 5%;">
          <div id="B1" class="question1" onclick="onSelect(event)">B) Jawaharlal Nehru
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <div id="C1" class="question1" onclick="onSelect(event)">C) Rajendra Prasad
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="positon: relative; right: 0; left: 5%;">
          <div id="D1" class="question1" onclick="onSelect(event)">D) Chandra Shekhar Azad
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Div's in the right cells are aligned to left side.

This will make them to float to the right side:

```
td:last-child div {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: you should not use float here. instead use `margin-left: auto;`

Comment: It worked, but are the two columns having the same width? If not how to do that?

Comment: floats are not meant to be used for layouting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777248/6357653

Comment: @Raja no they dont have the same width. you could fix this by adding: `table-layout: fixed` to the table (#test). However i'd recommend you to get used to [flexbox](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-flexbox-learning-through-examples-8c90248d4676) and get rid of those tables as [tables arent meant to be used for layouting eigher](https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html).