# Tic-Tac-Toe board not showing up on webpage

Tags: html, css

For some reason my css and html is not showing up on the webpage. It only shows the h1 title of Tic-Tac-Toe. I've written the code out to match what my homework list but I am missing something and I've started over several times and cannot seem to get what I am missing. maybe I'm reading the homework wrong?

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.top {
  padding: 3em;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.middle {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  border-left: 1px black solid;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}

.bottom {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 302px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<div id=b oard>
  <h1>TicTacToe</h1>
  <div class="row 1">
    <div class="top left"></div>
    <div class="top middle"></div>
    <div class="top right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row 2">
    <div class="middle left"></div>
    <div class=".center"></div>
    <div class="middle right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row 3">
    <div class="bottom left"></div>
    <div class="bottom middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: you should do the effort to reduce your content and keep the most relevant part ... no one want to waste 20min reading your homework ... and you have a typo `<div class= ".center"></div>` no need the dot

Answer (score 2):

In your code the first thing I noticed is that you're trying to display items where each one is wider than its container, so the three columns on each row overflows the row total width, so they stack on each other.

Try to use `box-sizing: border-box` [You can read about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

The important thing is:

It seems that this homework is somewhat old, as it gives tips to build the board using css in a manner we don't use anymore.

The `float` property is really not the best way to arrange the elements of the page. Since that property was created a long time ago, when the websites were very different, basically texts and images, it was intended mainly to arrange images inside blocks of text. So it produces some really weird results sometimes, if you don't have total knowledge of how it works. [see this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place)

You could try to use `flexbox`, once you study and understands the basics of how it works, your life would be a lot easier! 
[A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

With flexbox you could do something like:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
 <div id= board>
      <h1>TicTacToe</h1>
      <div class="row">
          <div class= "col"></div>
          <div class= "col"></div>
          <div class= "col"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class= "col"></div>
          <div class= "col"></div>
          <div class= "col"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class= "col"></div>
          <div class= "col"></div>
          <div class= "col"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I used margins and background colors just to make it easier to see the boxes, you can change it as you need.

Other way you could resolve this is by using [CSS Grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The essential mistake you made is that the different borders produce different heights and widths for those elements, since the 1px borders are *added*  to the height and width, and therefore some floating elements will go to the next row since there's 1px too little vertical space to make it fit in the same row, messing up the intended layout. (Some elements are 102 high, some 101px)

But if you add `box-sizing: border-box`, the border width is *included* in the height and width, so each of your element will really be 100x100px, including the borders.

That's done in my snippet below. The borders obviously are still not correct, but fixing that is up to you now...

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.top {
  padding: 3em;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.middle {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  border-left: 1px black solid;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}

.bottom {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 302px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<div id=b oard>
  <h1>TicTacToe</h1>
  <div class="row 1">
    <div class="top left"></div>
    <div class="top middle"></div>
    <div class="top right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row 2">
    <div class="middle left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="middle right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row 3">
    <div class="bottom left"></div>
    <div class="bottom middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```