# extend button top right corner

Tags: html, css

i need to create navigation as per below image

[image]

I have managed to bend down the right corner but I dont know how to extend top left corner.

[image]

here is the CSS i have used

```
   .btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle), .btn-group > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn 
 {
    border-top-right-radius: 21px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to push one button under the other one?
Also the last button isn't taking the `border-top-right-radius: 21px;`, isnt it be there as your original image shows?

Comment: for your css `.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle), .btn-group > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn` add padding-left:0 and margin-left:0;

Comment: @SubhenduKundu whichever the way all I need is first image output,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, you can not extend the corner.

But, you can use `margin-left: -...px` and `z-index` to make it works.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  padding: 4px;
}

.nav-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-container button {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px; /* <--- THIS */
  position: relative;
}

.nav-container button:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 2; /* <--- THIS */
}

.nav-container button:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 1; /* <--- THIS */
}

.nav-container button:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 0; /* <--- THIS */
}
.nav-container button:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #C38D8F;
}
.nav-container button:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CF1E22;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <button>Home</button>
    <button>Partner</button>
    <button>Product</button>
  </div>
  <button>Log out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi sorry for late response, actually the image you see is that when the user clicks on Partner button rest of the page opacity need to be changed its not color coding issue. can you help me with this? I have tried to change the opacity but it's still taking the whole button means z-index not working.

Comment: Why would you use `opacity` instead of just changing the color?

Comment: `opacity` is something user requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that manually adding `z-index` to each element is a good way to go especially if you will have more elements.

Here is an idea where you can use a pseudo element to create the overlapping part and have a more generic solution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  padding: 4px;
}

.nav-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-container {
  display:flex;
}
.nav-container button {
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-container button::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  left:100%;
  top:-2px;
  bottom:-2px;
  width:20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-left:none;
  background:inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.nav-container button:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #C38D8F;
}
.nav-container button:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CF1E22;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <button>Home</button>
    <button>Partner</button>
    <button>Product</button>
    <button>more button</button>
    <button>again</button>
  </div>
  <button>Log out</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping of one button over another button can be done simply using `margin-right` or `margin-left` with negative value.
The following example can solve your problem.

```
<div>
  <button class="btn">Product</button>
  <button class="btn">Partner</button>
  <button class="btn">Home</button>
</div>

button.btn {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: -7px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: right;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @praveen, might wanna look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place#9777248

Comment: Hmm, thats okay. But it is still one alternate solution for this problem...