# CSS: Multiline float alignment not working as desired

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

I have multiple lines im my html document, each of which is floating to the left. But my second line is not properly aligned to the left -- rather hard to explain, better just check out code and jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0j8kd4c3/

```html
<html>

<head>

    <style>

        label, input[type=text], button {
            float: left;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <label for="input1">LABEL 1</label>
    <input id="input1" type="text" />
    <button type="button">BUTTON</button>

    <br />

    <label for="input2">LABEL 2</label>
    <input id="input2" type="text" />

    <br />

    <label for="input3">LABEL 3</label>
    <input id="input3" type="text" />

</body>

</html>
```

Wrapping up line one in a `div` container doesn't help, so what can I do?

**Note that it's again working for line 3, which confuses me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `float` is only solution you are looking for, then you must be aware of `clear` property of CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Simply, apply `clear:both` on new row's div.

Here is complete solution:

```html
<html>

<head>

 <style>
 
  label, input[type=text], button {
   float: left;
  }
        .next{
          clear: both;
        }
 
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <label for="input">LABEL 1</label>
 <input id="input" type="text" />
 <button type="button">BUTTON</button>
  
 <div class="next"></div>
 <label for="anotherInput">LABEL 2</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Though, You shouldn't use `float` to layout your structures. That's a BAD practice.

Basically, as per my experience, `float` can have significant side-effects, that can directly affect your webpage.

Better, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777248/7847496

To simplify your answer, you have to wrap your each row inside `<div>...</div>` tag.
But with `float` property, parent 's height become zero.

Here a simple solution (with `display:inline-block`), that will work for you:

```html
<html>

<head>

 <style>
  label, input[type=text], button {
   display: inline-block;
  }
 
 </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <label for="input">LABEL 1</label>
    <input id="input" type="text" />
    <button type="button">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="anotherInput">LABEL 2</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks; but then I got spaces between the element, which I wanted to avoid (thus using `float`)

Comment: To remove spaces between `inline-block` elements, there is another fix. `float` isn't preferable approach for that.

Comment: Refer to these tricks, if you wish to remove spaces between: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you are using float for the lebel but remember it's working with the line height and the line the for lebel and text input is not same. You will understand when you use another 'br' in your code.

```
<body>
  <label for="input">LABEL 1</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button type="button">BUTTON</button>

  <br><br>

  <label for="anotherInput">LABEL 2</label>
</body>
```

Instead of use float, you can use 'display:inline-block'

```
  label, input[type=text], button {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way:

for example:

```html
<html>

<head>

 <style>
 
  label, input[type=text], button {
   float: left;
  }
 
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <div>
  
    <label for="input">LABEL 1</label>
 <input id="input" type="text" />
 <button type="button">BUTTON</button>
  </div>
 
 <br />
  <br />
 
 <div>
  
    <label for="anotherInput">LABEL 2</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```