# HTML signature , image is not placed next to the text

Tags: html, css

I have a signature on which i need to add image beside it. But i am not sure how exactly and what the css to be. Currently it is displayed below the text , where exactly should i place the image? In the same `tr` or `td` ?

```html
    <BODY style="font-size:10pt; font-family:Segoe UI, sans-serif;">
    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tbody style="vertical-align:top;">
    
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2" style="font-size:11pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold; color:#123E93">John Smith</span><br>
         <span>Sales Team</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="" style="font-size:8pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top">
        <span style="color:#123E93">Mobile </span><span>+359 88888888</span><br>
        <span style="color:#123E93">E-mail </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><span>email@gmaail.com</span></a><br>
        <span style="color:#123E93">Skype </span><span>skype ID</span><br>
        <span style="color:#123E93">Web </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank"><span>https://something.com/</span><br></a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <img src="png">
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can do it in several ways but let's try this one:

I see you were trying to use `colspan` whether you needed the `rowspan`. If you really want to use the image inside the table. The best and easy thing is to create an extra `<td>` in your first row only and use `rowspan=2` to enlarge until the next row like the following:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:11pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold; color:#123E93">John Smith</span><br>
      <span>Sales Team</span></td>
      <td rowspan="2" ><img width="150" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Kazuki_Nakajima_2008_Britain.jpg/1200px-Kazuki_Nakajima_2008_Britain.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="" style="font-size:8pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top">
      <span style="color:#123E93">Mobile </span><span>+359 88888888</span><br>
      <span style="color:#123E93">E-mail </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><span>email@gmaail.com</span></a><br>
      <span style="color:#123E93">Skype </span><span>skype ID</span><br>
      <span style="color:#123E93">Web </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank"><span>https://something.com/</span><br></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I like this solution, though i think image should be place outside the table...

Comment: @Jefry90 if this was the right answer for you then you should accept the answer as a right answer by clicking on the Tick icon.

Answer (score 0):

Move it outside the table and float it. Something like this maybe?

```html
<BODY style="font-size:10pt; font-family:Segoe UI, sans-serif;">
<img src="png" style="float: left;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody style="vertical-align:top;">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="font-size:11pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold; color:#123E93">John Smith</span><br>
     <span>Sales Team</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="" style="font-size:8pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top">
    <span style="color:#123E93">Mobile </span><span>+359 88888888</span><br>
    <span style="color:#123E93">E-mail </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><span>email@gmaail.com</span></a><br>
    <span style="color:#123E93">Skype </span><span>skype ID</span><br>
    <span style="color:#123E93">Web </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank"><span>https://something.com/</span><br></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

EDIT
As for @Paul comment, another layout can be this:

```html
<BODY style="font-size:10pt; font-family:Segoe UI, sans-serif;">
<img src="png" style="vertical-align: top;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: inline-block;">
 <tbody style="vertical-align:top;">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="font-size:11pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold; color:#123E93">John Smith</span><br>
     <span>Sales Team</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="" style="font-size:8pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top">
    <span style="color:#123E93">Mobile </span><span>+359 88888888</span><br>
    <span style="color:#123E93">E-mail </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><span>email@gmaail.com</span></a><br>
    <span style="color:#123E93">Skype </span><span>skype ID</span><br>
    <span style="color:#123E93">Web </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank"><span>https://something.com/</span><br></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Here i added to the `table` `display: inline-block;` and to the `img` `vertical-align: top;`

Anyway, you need to put out the image from the table.

Comment: [Avoid float](https://blog.prototypr.io/should-we-stop-using-floats-e01742a88f8d) at all costs.

Comment: OK will add another layout (:

Comment: Perhaps I should qualify that a little more. [This question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place) gives a little more insight into my statement.  Personally, I've never had anything good from them; they're confusing at the least, and can be destructive to your overall page design; it just takes a little change here or there to the HTML and you have to re-think chunks of mark-up.

Comment: you should try to apply Flexbox displaying

Comment: I guess it's an email template and flex won't work in all cases.

Comment: @myonline - With flexbox you do still need to [take into account older browsers](https://caniuse.com/) that don't support it.

Comment: What @Paul wrote + this is something that good-old `display: inline-block` can help you without adjusting and extra code the other elements.

Comment: @Paul - flexbox now is supported to old browsers like ie11 and up.

Comment: @A.Meshu - the OP didn't say that this was an email template.  If it is the case, then all CSS is severely restricted.

Comment: This will work with all email apps including old outlook.

Comment: @myonline - [No, it's not](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexb). IE11, like Edge and even Chrome has partial support for Flexbox. IE11 has a very poor support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new cell within the same row as the name and then set a `colspan="2"` to a cell in a row below. That way you will keep everything within the table.

```html
<BODY style="font-size:10pt; font-family:Segoe UI, sans-serif;">
    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tbody style="vertical-align:top;">
    
      <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="png">
       </td>
       <td style="font-size:11pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top"><span style="font-weight: bold; color:#123E93">John Smith</span><br>
         <span>Sales Team</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2" style="font-size:8pt; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:0; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; vertical-align:top;" valign="top">
        <span style="color:#123E93">Mobile </span><span>+359 88888888</span><br>
        <span style="color:#123E93">E-mail </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="mailto:email@gmail.com"><span>email@gmaail.com</span></a><br>
        <span style="color:#123E93">Skype </span><span>skype ID</span><br>
        <span style="color:#123E93">Web </span><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #2a2a2a;" href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank"><span>https://something.com/</span><br></a>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will have to be placed in the second `<td>` of one of the `<tr>`s. `colspan="2"` takes the space of two `<td>`s, even if it is only one in the first `<tr>`. Example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>John Smith</strong><br />
            Sales Team</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile +359 88888888<br />
            E-mail <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmaail.com</a><br />
            Skype skype ID<br />
            Web <a href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank">https://something.com/</a></td>
            <td><img src="png" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(I guess this is for some email signature)

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>John Smith</strong><br />
            Sales Team</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile +359 88888888<br />
            E-mail <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmaail.com</a><br />
            Skype skype ID<br />
            Web <a href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank">https://something.com/</a></td>
            <td><img src="png" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can join two cells in a column as well:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align:top"><strong>John Smith</strong><br />
   Sales Team</td>
   <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top"><img src="png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align:top">Mobile +359 88888888<br />
   E-mail <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmaail.com</a><br />
   Skype skype ID<br />
   Web <a href="https://www.something.com/" target="_blank">https://something.com/</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```