# Misalignment of <div> for UTF-8 Japanese chars

Tags: html, css, utf-8, cjk, html-encode

```css
.element-label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 260px;
  padding-left: .5em;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #A00000;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

.element-value {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="field1">
  <span class="element-label">Label 1 </span>
  <span class="element-value">テスト </span>
</div>
<br />
<div id="field2">
  <span class="element-label">Label 2 </span>
  <span class="element-value">testing value</span>
</div>
```

In MS IE:

[image: IE for Japanese chars]

However, in Chrome or MS Edge:
the html looks like:
[image: Chrome/Edge for Japanese chars]

**The layout in IE is what I expect/want.**

However, when I change to the Japanese chars to other language chars (English, Chinese, Korean, etc.).
They all look right.

[image: All browsers for non-Japanese chars]

1. How can I format the Japanese chars correctly in this case
2. Why Japanese chars are so special in this case in different browsers provided that they are all UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why Japanese chars are so special in this case in different browsers
>   provided that they are all UTF-8 encoded?

They are special because they use different font and therefore are taller than Latin characters. You can see the same result if you use Latin text, but increase the `font-size` for that specific value `span`.

However the main problem is that your wrapper `div` elements are basically non-existent and not forcing child elements to be in rows and therefore each element is trying to be next to its sibling. If you removed the `br` element you would see that there is only one row.

A better solution is to use css to order your elements into rows and remove the `br` completely. Simple way to do that is to use `flex` on your wrapper elements. Also you should fix the height of rows to get a more consistent appearance (I added `line-height` to counter that).

```css
.element-label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 260px;
  padding-left: .5em;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #A00000;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

.element-value {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 9pt;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 9pt;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="field1">
  <span class="element-label">Label 1 </span>
  <span class="element-value">テスト </span>
</div>
<div class="row" id="field2">
  <span class="element-label">Label 2 </span>
  <span class="element-value">testing value</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much with clear explanation on the root cause, you save me another few hours. Fixing the height seems needs to hardcode a number there. Just wonder if there is any standard/common way to have <div> rendered at a new row/line. Just saw that someone else is suggesting <br style="clear:both" /> at another post.

Comment: `clear: both;` does work, but as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place) floats are not meant for layouts. Since the introduction of flexbox it is easy to make responsive layouts if you have proper wrapper elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Indeed, there is no responsive layout requirement at my case and a table should be good enough.