# Is the float property deprecated in CSS?

Tags: css

Is it true that the `float` property is deprecated?

If so, what alternative should I use instead?

```
#security .security-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

#security {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/9zj3.jpg') no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#security .security-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

#security .security-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #c22312;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="security">
<div class="security-wrapper">
   <div class="security-title">Security investment solutions</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what makes you think that float would be dumped?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `float` isn't deprecated, there are better layout properties to work with now - `flex` and `grid`. If your code works, you're fine.

Comment: According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=float), float isn't deprecated. Your code should function on about 97.14% of all browsers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the initial assumption of the question is false - since float is not deprecated and the code works.

Comment: @Johannes: I read it on the internet

Comment: @bouns where did you read this - as in the site/resource?

Comment: @disinfor: Sorry it was on a forum french.

Comment: float is still very useful for floating images or other elements where you want the neghboring text to flow under the floated element if it is too long to just be at the side.

Comment: Going forward on your coding journey, I would look at `flex` and `grid` instead of using floats (you can avoid a ton of headaches) for layouts. A Haworth is right about using `float` for elements that may have text wrap around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it works well as far as I think.

and no, the `float` property is not deprecated yet in CSS, you can still use it.
but for an advanced and more clean easy code, you better use `flexbox`

your code can be then something like that:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#security {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/9zj3.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex; /* displaying it as a flexbox */
  justify-content: end; /* shifting its content to the end "right" */
}

#security .security-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  width: 50%;
}

#security .security-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #c22312;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="security">
  <div class="security-wrapper">
    <div class="security-title">Security investment solutions</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can learn more about flexbox here:

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: This question does not need an answer as the initial premise of the question is incorrect. There was already an answer that was the same as yours and deleted for this reason. Also, the HTML in your snippet has an error, since you're missing the closing `<div>`

Comment: @disinfor A mistaken premise does not an off-topic question make.

Comment: @TylerH I'm voting to change your name to TylerHYoda :) I don't think the question was necessarily off-topic - at the time of this question, there was an answer that was essentially the same as this. That said, I wish there as an answer somewhere on Stack Overflow that was the definitive "Stop using floats for layouts" that we could mark as a duplicate every time a float layout question comes up.

Comment: @disinfor Well there is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/are-floats-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place which might work as a dupe. I'll read the Q above again and see if it would fit. EDIT: Yep, looks like a good fit to me

Comment: @TylerH nice find! I'm going to save that to my snippets.