# Coding a blockquote with icon and responsive border wrap with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive

How might something like this be coded using HTML & CSS? Primarily the icon situated next to some text with border wrapping the text/copy. Initial approach is using an SVG but I can't seem to make it work. Is this even possible? Perhaps the only way would be to use non-transparent graphics and overlay them on top of a div with the text that has the radius border applied through CSS?

This is already being [used in production](https://innovista-health.com/value-based-care-services/) to some extent. You can see these blockquotes appear on page in a couple of places.

**This is what I have:**

```css
.gray_box_conten {
  background-color: #e7e4f0;
  max-width: 890px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.gray_box_conten,
.white_box {
  min-height: 162px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  display: flex;
}

.man-QA {
  max-width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.risk_adjustment .content_wrap1,
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.Quality__frequently,
.error-page .container,
.map_grid img,
.menuLink ul li.current-menu-parent a::after,
.news_box_btn .btn_cta {
  width: 100%;
}

.Quality__frequently p {
  color: #22003f;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray_box_conten">
  <div class="man-QA">
    <img src="https://innovista-health.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/qa-info-blurb-icon.svg" alt="" title="qa-info-blurb-icon"> </div>
  <div class="Quality__frequently">
    <p>Quality performance success frequently results in higher distribution of shared savings and incentive payments.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is what I want:** It needs to be responsive and support any background colour.

[image: ![info blurb image]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your best attempt so we have something to work with.

Comment: Yes it's possible but it is expected that you attempt this yourself and we can assist with any problems you might have.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is already being used in production to some extent. You can see on https://innovista-health.com/value-based-care-services/ these blockquotes appear on page in a couple of places. Hope this helps clarify things, and ensure that I have in fact attempted this so far. Thank you.

Comment: Shame the question was closed since I have a solution to this. Why not edit your question to include a snippet of what you currently have (rather than linking to site which may no longer be available for future readers)?

Comment: This approach might work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/moob/7rg4dav8/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this.

- Use a `blockquote` with a rounded border.
- Convert the SVG to a data-uri, remove its white background and use it as a [`:before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) of the `blockquote`.
- Give this `:before`  pseudo-element a `background-color` so that the `blockquote`'s border does not show through.
- Set the `background-color` as a [css variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) so we only have to change it in one place.
- Wrap the `blockquote` in a container that we can position and style. This is where the `--bg` variable is assigned.

**Demo:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&family=Poppins&display=swap');
:root {
  --bg: #eee;
}
html, body {margin:0;}
body {
  display: grid;
  gap:20px;
  height: 100vh; 
  place-items: center;
  background: var(--bg, #eee);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  padding:20px;
}
/* The above is just for demo. */
.blockquote-container {
  --bg: white;
  background:var(--bg);
  max-width:min(100%,560px);
  padding:30px;
  border-radius:20px;  
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.blockquote-container.bg2 {
  --bg: #e7e4f0;
}
.blockquote-container.bg2:hover {
  --bg: #adb;
}
blockquote {
  display:flex;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid #68519f;
  border-radius:8px;
  padding:0.5em 1em;
  background:var(--bg, white);
  font-size:0.8rem;
  margin:0 0 0 30px;
  min-height:4em;
}
blockquote:before {
  content:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:serif='http://www.serif.com/' width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 47 44' version='1.1' xml:space='preserve' style='display:none; fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;'%3E%3Cg id='quote'%3E%3Ccircle class='c' cx='21.035' cy='20.84' r='20.775' style='fill:none;'%3E%3C/circle%3E%3Cpath class='c' d='M30.538,34.093l3.75,0.247l6,4.92l0.247,-5.002l3.083,-0.833l1.747,-2.167l0,-14.333l-1.665,-1.417l-2.415,-0.668l-18.832,0.668l0.915,15.165l0.915,2.25l3.502,1.417l2.753,-0.247Z' style='fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M21.59,43.153c-4.47,-0 -8.925,-1.38 -12.682,-4.103c-9.638,-6.982 -11.79,-20.505 -4.808,-30.142c6.99,-9.638 20.513,-11.79 30.143,-4.808l-0.878,1.215c-8.962,-6.502 -21.547,-4.492 -28.05,4.47c-6.502,8.963 -4.492,21.548 4.47,28.05c6.36,4.605 14.88,5.085 21.713,1.208l0.742,1.305c-3.307,1.875 -6.982,2.805 -10.65,2.805Z' style='fill:%2379cbc5;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M15.133,35.248c-0.12,-0 -0.248,-0.023 -0.368,-0.075c-0.337,-0.143 -0.555,-0.48 -0.555,-0.84l0,-4.688l-0.397,0c-2.483,0 -4.5,-2.025 -4.5,-4.5l-0,-12.255c-0,-2.482 2.017,-4.5 4.5,-4.5l22.68,0c2.482,0 4.5,2.018 4.5,4.5l-0,12.255c-0,2.483 -2.018,4.5 -4.5,4.5l-15.053,0l-5.685,5.355c-0.172,0.165 -0.405,0.248 -0.63,0.248l0.008,-0Zm-1.313,-25.028c-1.462,0 -2.662,1.193 -2.662,2.663l-0,12.255c-0,1.47 1.192,2.662 2.662,2.662l1.313,0c0.502,0 0.915,0.413 0.915,0.915l-0,3.473l4.402,-4.14c0.173,-0.165 0.398,-0.248 0.63,-0.248l15.42,0c1.47,0 2.663,-1.192 2.663,-2.662l-0,-12.255c-0,-1.463 -1.193,-2.663 -2.663,-2.663l-22.68,0Z' style='fill:%2368519f;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M41.878,13.753l-0.878,-0l0,1.837l0.87,0c1.463,0 2.655,1.193 2.655,2.663l0,12.255c0,1.47 -1.192,2.662 -2.655,2.662l-1.312,0c-0.51,0 -0.923,0.413 -0.923,0.923l0,3.472l-4.395,-4.147c-0.172,-0.165 -0.397,-0.248 -0.63,-0.248l-7.815,0c-1.47,0 -2.662,-1.192 -2.662,-2.662l-0,-0.87l-1.838,-0l0,0.87c0,2.482 2.018,4.5 4.5,4.5l7.448,-0l5.685,5.355c0.172,0.165 0.397,0.255 0.63,0.255c0.12,-0 0.247,-0.03 0.367,-0.075c0.338,-0.15 0.555,-0.48 0.555,-0.848l0,-4.687l0.398,-0c2.482,-0 4.5,-2.018 4.5,-4.5l-0,-12.255c-0,-2.483 -2.018,-4.5 -4.5,-4.5Z' style='fill:%2368519f;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M26.99,15.013l-11.91,-0c-0.51,-0 -0.922,-0.413 -0.922,-0.923c-0,-0.51 0.412,-0.922 0.922,-0.922l11.91,-0c0.503,-0 0.915,0.412 0.915,0.922c0,0.51 -0.412,0.923 -0.915,0.923Z' style='fill:%2368519f;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M26.99,19.933l-11.91,-0c-0.51,-0 -0.922,-0.413 -0.922,-0.915c-0,-0.503 0.412,-0.923 0.922,-0.923l11.91,0c0.503,0 0.915,0.413 0.915,0.923c0,0.51 -0.412,0.915 -0.915,0.915Z' style='fill:%2368519f;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M26.99,24.86l-11.91,0c-0.51,0 -0.922,-0.412 -0.922,-0.922c-0,-0.51 0.412,-0.923 0.922,-0.923l11.91,0c0.503,0 0.915,0.413 0.915,0.923c0,0.51 -0.412,0.922 -0.915,0.922Z' style='fill:%2368519f;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M31.003,17.803l-0,-2.108l4.305,0l-0,7.035l1.357,0l0,2.108l-5.662,-0l-0,-2.108l1.387,0l0,-4.927l-1.387,-0Zm1.282,-4.725c0,-0.443 0.158,-0.818 0.465,-1.133c0.315,-0.315 0.69,-0.472 1.125,-0.472c0.435,-0 0.825,0.157 1.133,0.472c0.307,0.315 0.465,0.69 0.465,1.133c-0,0.442 -0.158,0.81 -0.465,1.125c-0.315,0.307 -0.69,0.465 -1.125,0.465c-0.435,-0 -0.81,-0.158 -1.125,-0.473c-0.315,-0.315 -0.473,-0.69 -0.473,-1.117Z' style='fill:%23f38076;fill-rule:nonzero;'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width:70px;
  height:67px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin:-15px 1em -35px -50px;
  background:var(--bg, white);
  border-radius:50% 50% 10px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockquote-container">
<blockquote>
Quality performance success frequently results in higher distribution of shared savings and incentive payments.
</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="blockquote-container bg2">
<blockquote>
Have a different background colour if you like. The background colour is a css variable so you can add a custom class in your stylesheet or set the `--bg` in your inline style.
</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="blockquote-container" style="--bg:#fff9c0">
<blockquote>
Resize your browser to see how these flow.
</blockquote>
</div>

<blockquote>
You don't have to have the container but it will fallback to whatever your --bg is set to else white.
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this is possible by the use of html and css like use can use float left property to make the image and text align horizontally and the if you try to add border to div element the image will overflow .so to align it make it come inside the border you can add property like overflow auto to div element.
Ex:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>overflow</title>
<style>
div{
overflow:auto;
}
img{
float:right;//your choice you can write left or right
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="write the path for image source">
here you can write the text you want to display.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome!! [Do not use floats for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/is-float-for-layout-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place). There are much better ways to do what OP is asking.