# Is there a way to show columns side by side on desktop and one below the other on mobile with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I am new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to format the result of my code so that the page is responsive and it looks one way on mobile and another way on desktop for better readability. I have made it looking at the W3.School tutorials and I have a nav bar on the side while the main text is divided into two columns set up with flex. I would like to make it so that the two columns show up underneath each other when the screen is smaller.

Here is the link to codepen to take a look at what I've done so far: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Estelle-Bollei/pen/mdgwebm)

```css
  header {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: times new roman;
}

p {
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 18px;
  color
}

p.ex1 {
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

p.ex2 {
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

p.ex3 {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

p.indented-paragraph {
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.left {
  float: left;
}

div.right {
  float: right;
}

div.columns {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

div.columns>div {
  width: 50%;
}

section {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

a:link {
  color: darkslateblue;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
  color: mediumorchid;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: lavender;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

article {
  -webkit-flex: 3;
  -ms-flex: 3;
  flex: 3;
  background-color: snow;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  section {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .container .div.columns .section .nav .article .ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        <h3>Patented Dec. 28, 1943</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h3>2,337,621</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h2><b>UNITED STATES PATENT OFFICE</b></h2>

    <h3 style="text-align: center;">
      2,337,621
    </h3>

    <h1><b>TIMING DEVICE FOR SCRIPT READING</b></h1>

    <p style="text-align: center;" class="ex1">
      William S. Peevey, Oakland, Calif.
      <br> Application March 20, 1941, Serial No. 384,357
      <br> 2 Claims. (CL 40—31)
    </p>
  </header>

  <section>
    <nav>
      <ul>

        <li>
          <h2><b>Contents</b></h2>
        </li>
        <br>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Page-1">Page 1</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Page-2">Page 2</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Page-3">Page 3</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-1">Figure 1</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li> <a href="#Figure-2">Figure 2</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-3">Figure 3</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-4">Figure 4</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-5">Figure 5</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-6">Figure 6</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-7">Figure 7</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-8">Figure 8</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-9">Figure 9</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-10">Figure 10</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-11">Figure 11</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-12">Figure 12</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-13">Figure 13</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-14">Figure 14</a></li>
        </p>
        <p class="ex2">
          <li><a href="#Figure-15">Figure 15</a></li>
        </p>

      </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>

      <h2 id="Page-1" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">Page 1</h2>

      <div class="columns">

        <div>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">This invention relates to a new and useful im-
            <br> proved script reading timing device that is adapt-
            <br> ed for use in radio broadcasting and all other
            <br> types of scrip reading.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">It is an object of the present invention to pro-
            <br> vide a specially constructed device of the charac-
            <br> ter described that can be made miniature in size
            <br> and operated and controlled in an exceptionally
            <br> simple manner.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">It is another object of the invention to provide
            <br> two spools for carrying script tape and means
            <br> for automatically conveying the tape from one
            <br> spool to the other and past a time indicator.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">It is another object of the invention to control
            <br> the conveying of said tape by the combination
            <br> of an electric motor and a mechanical motor.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">It is another object of the invention to provide
            <br> means for producing a continuous pulling tension
            <br> on the tape while it is being unwound from the
            <br> primary spool.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">Another object of the invention is to provide
            <br> means for conveying the tape past a time indi-
            <br> cator at a constant unchanging speed and to also
            <br> provide means for enabling the speed to be
            <br> changed if desired.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">Another object of the invention is to provide
            <br> improved means for controlling the device in a
            <br> manner that will enable the reading to be re-
            <br> hearsed.
          </p>
          <p class="indented-paragraph">The invention further consists in the particu-
            <br> lar combination, construction and association of
            <br> the different parts, such as described in the fol-
            <br> lowing specification, and possesses various other
            <br> objects and features of advantage which will be
            <br> apparent during the course of the following
            <br> description.
          </p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">In the accompanying drawings forming a part
            <br> of this specification and in which like numerals
            <br> are employed to designate like parts throughout
            <br> the same,</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%201.png" target="_blank">Fig. 1</a> is a top plan view of the device and par-
            <br> ticularly shows two elongated cylindrical hous-
            <br> ings, one a primary housing from which the tape
            <br> is drawn, and the other a secondary housing into
            <br> which the tape is conveyed;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%202.png" target="_blank">Fig. 2</a> is an outer end view of a cap that fits on
            <br> the left end of the secondary housing;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%203.png" target="_blank">Fig. 3</a> is a central vertical sectional view of said
            <br> cap and a mechanical motor that is mounted
            <br> therein;
          </p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%204.png" target="_blank">Fig. 4</a> is a sectional view taken on the line
            <b>4—4</b>
            <br> of Fig. 3, looking in the direction of the arrows,
            <br> and shows a coiled spring and the preferred con-
            <br> struction of the mechanical motor;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%205.png" target="_blank">Fig. 5</a> is a longitudinal side elevational view of
            <br> the primary housing with a portion of the hous-
            <br> ing wall broken away to show a specially con-
            <br> structed spool for carrying the tape and one of
            <br> the rollers that is provided for controlling the
            <br> tape;
          </p>

        </div>

        <div>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%206.png" target="_blank">Fig. 6</a> is a view showing the manner in which
            <br> an idler roller is mounted in the secondary hous-
            <br> ing;
          </p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%207.png" target="_blank">Fig. 7</a> is a fragmentary end sectional view taken
            <br> on the line <b>7—7</b> of <a href="Figure%201.png" target="_blank">Fig. 1</a>, looking in the direction
            <br> of the arrows, illustrating the manner in which
            <br> the tape travels from the primary housing to the
            <br> secondary housing and past the reading point of
            <br> time, and showing in elevation the lids that are
            <br> hinged to the lower right ends of said housings;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%208.png" target="_blank">Fig. 8</a> is an inside plan view of a cap that is
            <br> mounted on the left end of the primary housing,
            <br> said cap containing the electric motor and reduc-
            <br> ing gears for imparting revolvable movement to
            <br> the spool in said housing;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%209.png" target="_blank">Fig. 9</a> is a central longitudinal enlarged broken
            <br> sectional view of the primary housing, spool
            <br> therein, and spool winder in the right end there-
            <br> of, showing in elevation the electric motor and
            <br> reducing gears in the left end thereof;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%2010.png" target="_blank">Fig. 10</a> is a vertical sectional view taken on
            <br> the line <b>10—10</b> of <a href="Figure%209.png" target="_blank">Fig. 9</a>, looking in the direction
            <br> of the arrows;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%2011.png" target="_blank">Fig. 11</a> is a vertical sectional view taken on the
            <br>
            <b>line 11—11</b> of <a href="Figure%209.png" target="_blank">Fig. 9</a>, looking in the direction of
            <br> the arrows;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%2012.png" target="_blank">Fig. 12</a> is a longitudinal view of the driven roll-
            <br> er shaft and illustrates the manner in which the
            <br> same is revolubly supported in the prmary hous-
            <br> ing and provided with a pinion that is capable of
            <br> engaging with the gears driven by the electric
            <br> motor;
          </p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%2013.png" target="_blank">Fig. 13</a> is a longitudinal side elevational view
            <br> of the adjustable shaft and illustrates the man-
            <br> ner in which the same is revolubly supported on
            <br> a pair of adjusting levers that are mounted in
            <br> the primary housing;</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%2014.png" target="_blank">Fig. 14</a> is a top plan view of said adjustable
            <br> shaft and levers and illustrates the manner in
            <br> which the levers are connected together; and</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph"><a href="Figure%2015.png" target="_blank">Fig. 15</a> is a diagrammatic view, illustrating a
            <br> plurality of the script timing devices and the con-
            <br> trols for separately operating the same.</p>

          <p class="indented-paragraph">In the accompanying drawings wherein for
            <br> the purpose of illustration is shown a preferred
            <br> embodiment of my invention, the numeral <b>17</b>
            <br> designates the primary housing and the numeral
            <br>
            <b>18</b> the secondary housing, both of which are
            <br> preferably made of sheet metal and cylindrically
            <br> formed and provided with slots <b>19</b> and <b>20</b>, re-
            <br> spectively, through the cylindrical walls thereof,
            <br> as shown in Figs. <a href="Figure%201.png" target="_blank">1</a> and <a href="Figure%207.png" target="_blank">7</a>. Covers
            <b>21</b> and <b>22</b>
            <br> are hinged, respectively, to the right ends of said
            <br> housings <b>17</b> and <b>18</b> by suitable hinges <b>23</b> and <b>24</b>,
            <br> respectively, and an intermediate member or
            <br> handle <b>25</b> is provided for holding the housings
            <br> together, as shown in Figs. <a href="Figure%201.png" target="_blank">1</a> and <a href="Figure%207.png" target="_blank">7</a>. A pair of
            <br> suitable guides <b>26</b> and <b>27</b> extends over both of
            <br> said housings for carrying the tape from one
            <br> housing to the other and are fastened to the cyl-</p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <hr style="height:2px;border- 
width:0;width:50%;color:lightblue;background-color:lightblue">
```

I would be very thankful if someone managed to figure out how I can make the columns layout responsive, as I have only managed to make the nav bar shift based on screen size.

I tried to use the responsive web design framework W3.CSS as seen on https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp but it didn't work. I might have made a mistake in applying the code though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, please [try not to use float for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776840/is-float-for-layout-bad-what-should-be-used-in-its-place). You may want to consider a different tutorial, W3schools is not a reliable resource.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hello, I've added part of my HTML code as it's very long. The full thig can be found on the link to codepen. Is there any other place to find reliable tutorials? This is for a uni assignment and the main resource they provided was the w3school website

Comment: no need for multiple `font-family: times new roman;` here.  You probably have much more CSS than really needed.  FWIW your CSS as posted is malformed/broken.

Comment: Your HTML is also broken as an `<li` MUST be a direct decent of a `ul` or `ol`

Comment: I formatted to show the broken code easier.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean about the broken css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  section {
    -webkit-flex-direction: columns;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .container .div.columns .section .nav .article .ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Just like you change `flex-direction` for your `section`, because the `display: flex` that the `section` has automatically put its underlying children as columns, you also need to change `flex-direction` on your `div.columns` so the text goes from column to row when the width is 620px or less.

You can have several selectors share the same CSS styling, in this case `section` and `.columns` as shown below.

```
  section, .columns {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

ADDITION
Also, a quick fix for when the text wraps in an incorrect way on smaller screens, replace your current CSS selector with the following:

```
div.columns > div {
  /* width: 50%  old value */
  width: 60ch /* width is 60 characters long */
}
```

... OR

```
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .container .div.columns .section .nav .article .ul, div.columns > div {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: While this answer may be useful, you should probably wait until OP provides their HTML, and give them a little more help, since they are a beginner. There's enough wrong with the tutorial they are following, that this answer is really only the tip of the iceberg, so to speak, in terms of what they need help with.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? I added a snippet to my html. I am very new to this and the only source they made available to us is W3school, so I've tried to cobble together a code based on the various w3school tutorials. For context, I am supposed to create a digitally readable version of an old patent using CSS and HTML only, and I wanted to keep the original division into two columns for desktop. As it needs to be readable on mobile too, I wanted to have the two columns turn into one according to screen size. Thank you!

Comment: I extended my answer, and fixed a typo where I wrote `.column` instead of `.columns`.

Comment: Thank you that worked! the only issue is that when i reduce the screen size, especially when it turns into only one column, the lines get broken into two even when there's enough space for the original full line to show on screen. Is there a way to fix that? As it is a patent, i want the reader to be able to refer to specific lines, and when they get split in half this becomes harder

Comment: The text is crammed because `.columns > div` has a width of 50%. You could remove that in your media query but ... the real problem stems from you using `<br>` to manually break text lines in order to control the text. You should _always_ let text run freely. Instead of having `div.columns > div { width: 50% }` change that to `div.columns > div { width: 60ch }` - meaning that the width is 60 characters long.